# Call for a diamond to rename a misspelled tag

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I just discovered that one of tags used about 7 times is misspelled.

[langauges](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/langauges) should be [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages)!

I retagged two questions manually thinking they were the only ones. Then I realized there were more and the existing tag has a wiki so it's probably better to rename the tag or somehow merge the old tag into the new tag if that preserves its wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I see somebody merged these in some way or other, but they way you chose to do it resulted in the loss of the tag wiki I warned about.

Sorry I don't know the diamond/mod tools so I don't know what options exist.

Comment: Yeah was just trying it, there was a brief panic as the tag listing then only showed 2 'languages' and no bad spelling ones, but it turned out to be just slow in updating.    However the wiki was lost as you can only merge the title, and it doesn't merge the wiki, it would seem.  I'm going to go and add one for it now, just so we don't have degradation ;)

Comment: done now, and I'm off to bed as clearly I need sleep!

Comment: Thanks man! Yeah a lot of things have a bit of a delay due to the nature of how distributed databases work )-:

Comment: In case you ever need it again, @Mark - "lost" tag wikis can be found [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis) (also linked to from the mods tools).

Comment: Much appreciated @Shog9 :)